# How do I change the name of a command button in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I feel like such a dunce, but I cannot figure out how/where to do this.

I've pasted a command button into a sheet and it came in with a default name of "Button 1".  I cannot figure out where in the interface to go to change the button's name.  (I can change the button's label text, I'm actually interested in renaming the button itself).

I've tried clicking "Design Mode" in the Developer Ribbon, but that does not seem to give me any additional interfaces or options for setting the button's attributes.

Help! (FYI: using Excel 2010).

Comment: click on the `Properties` button to the left of the `Design Mode` button. then click the object you want to rename

Comment: @Brad, thanks.  I tried that (I hadn't tried clicking Properties, then  the Button, so you've moved me forward).  However, when I click Properties (to the *right* of the Design Mode icon), then click the button, it doesn't show me properties for the button.  Instead, it shows me properties for Module1.  I've tried dropping down the list in properties combo box, to see if the button is listed, but it's not. What next, do you know? Thanks!

Comment: This question is answered, but here's an important addendum: *There is a 32-character limit on the length of Command Button names.* The behavior if you enter a name longer than 32 characters is that Excel seems to ignore your input—no error message is given, but your changes are rolled back. When this happened to me, I thought there must be some other panel or setting I needed to use, maybe there was some workbook corruption, etc. Once I figured out that the issue was just the name length, I experimented to confirm that on Excel 2010, 32 is the maximum length.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the name of the button (as well as any other object/chart) by selecting and typing in the small Name box left of the formula bar (confirm it by pressing Enter):

[image]

Comment: This is the only solution that is actually working, at least with Excel 2007.

Comment: This does not work at all for me. The field is not editable

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click on the command button, choose "command button object" and then choose "edit"

Answer (score 0):

Select the Design mode on , right click properties " Alphabetic" change the name on caption to your desired name.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're trying to name the button the same name as one of your procedures or a cell reference or possibly something else that already exists; otherwise, you should be able to right-click you button to select then change the name in the name box left of the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this answer might help others that are struggling to achieve this.

There are two types of buttons that user can add on a worksheet.

- Form Control Button
- ActiveX Control Button

1st (Form Control Button):

- If you have added the button as a Form Control via Developer tab and under the Insert -> Form Controls -> Button

[Adding Form Control Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxErt.png)

Then changing the name of this type of button can be done via the address bar:

- Right click on the button and then click somewhere else to leave it in design mode and then change the name on the button in the address bar

[Changing name of Form Control Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZI5.png)

2nd (ActiveX Control Button)

- If you have added the button as an ActiveX Control Button via Developer tab and under the Insert -> ActiveX Controls -> Button

[Adding ActiveX Control Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNY4Z.png)

Then changing the name can be done via properties window AND the address bar

[Changing Name Of ActiveX Control Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgcHL.png)

3rd (Changing the name via VBA)
You can always use VBA to change the name of the button, you just need to access your worksheet Buttons collection and change it from there:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Name = "ChangeNameHere"
```

Answer (score 0):

It drove me crazy for awhile, trying this and that and suggestions. I have office 2019, and every time I right clicked on the button, I would get a Move and Copy menu and I would just click somewhere else to get out of the menu. But finally I decided to just hit Escape to rid the menu. This kept button sizing outline, and I was able to place my cursor in the middle of the button and was able to change the name. Note: Do Not Hit The Enter Key or it will erase the text and boot you out. Just click off the button.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of years removed, but click on design node then click on your button, and you will get bars, right click and click properties, change the name in "caption" to the one you want it to be, click the "X", then click design mode again.